# Set up user's profile on a new Windows domain computer without user's password or reset

Tags: windows, active-directory, user-profile

Is it possible to set up a profile for a current user on a new computer on a Windows domain without knowing the user's password or resetting the password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, no. When we were doing our computer labs for students, we ended up preparing the Default Profile to be pretty close to what they actually needed. This is the preferred method of doing it for Windows, other methods are prone to wacky and subtle problems.

Comment: Between tweaking the Default User profile, using Group Policy, and writing logon scripts, you should be able to customize the user's initial profile pretty severely w/o ever needing to logon as the user.